# How do I use mathlibplot.hist with x and y values using bins=40 in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, histogram, histogram2d

I have a large list of data points of x and y values that I need to put into a histogram with 40 bins but mathlibplot.hist is only letting me enter 1 variable with bins. I've tried hist2d as well but it's not very clean. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to create on two histograms in one axes or separate histograms for x and y?

Answer (score 0):

As you have data points x and y, you can simply use hist method to plot histogram.
The following code will help you to create a histogram.

```
plt.hist([x,y],bins=40, histtype='step',fill=True)
plt.show()
```

The histogram will look like the following:

[image]

If you want to change the style or give it title and labels, you can do it. Here is another histogram with unfilled bars.

[image: Histogram 2]

If you still face any problem, let me know then.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can make use of matplotlib library to solve your purpose:
It will be like imposing 2 histograms on top of each other.
In the below code, I am trying to plot a histograms of y_train and predicted(X_train) in the same space. 
You can modify the variables as per your requirement.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(y_train, stacked=True,bins=40, label='Actual', alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(regressor.predict(X_train),bins=40, stacked=True, label='Predicted', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!